# copying pointer characters not working as expected

Tags: c, eclipse, string, pointers, mingw

In the following code, what am I doing wrong? I run the code in eclipse and using MinGW C compiler. When I run it eclipse stops responding. When I debug the code, it breaks on the line

```
*start = *end;
```

I verified the value of *start and *end in debug mode and none is null.

```
void func1(char *str)
{
    char *end, *start;
    end = start = str;
    char tmp;

    if (str)
    {
        while (*end)
            ++end;
        --end;

        while (start < end) 
        {
            tmp = *start;
            *start = *end;
            *end = tmp;

            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips/ideas?

Comment: Could be a lot of things, maybe you are using a string literal? Providing a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) would allow us to help you better.

Comment: It's almost certainly due to passing in a read-only string literal, but you also have another problem: if the string is the empty string `""`, then the decrement of `--end` puts `end` before the start of the string, and that's technically Undefined Behavior, though that's highly unlikely to cause any practical problems.

Comment: How do you know that `--end` is legal?

Comment: Works for me.  What are you passing to it?

Comment: I'm passing "Hello World". When the code reaches that line, *start has 'H' and *end has 'd' in debug window. and "Hello World" is also defined as char pointer in the main function that calls func1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So according to your feedback your are passing a string literal, `"Hello World"` to `func1`, modifying a string literal is undefined behavior, you could alternatively use something like this and it will work:

```
char arr1[] = "hello world" ;
func1(arr1) ;
```

Although as Adam and Kerrek pointed out you need to add more error checking to you code but this should fix your immediate problem.